# Conflict between bootstrap and interact.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop, interact.js

I am trying to use the `interact.js` plugin for drag&drop with bootstrap. That works but when I put a draggable box in a nav it stops working.

**For better understanding:**
https://jsfiddle.net/4ddoqcpj/

"Beat-TEST" works well but the other (in the nav) fall and won't stay in the dragzone.

Can anyone help me ? Please! That for school but my teacher doesn't know how to use bootstrap and all...

Comment: Hey Pierre, can you please specify what "stops working" and what you expect to happen (visualize it maybe)?

Comment: Hey! Did you see the link ? I just said the box named"Beat-Test" work so that what I want for all. "Beat-Long1" and"Beat gras" dont do the same thing ... You understood?

Comment: You edited your post to include the text which doesn't add value to the question, they were removed [for a reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Hey, I saw you posted a reaction as answer but I think it got removed because it was no answer. Maybe try editing your question or just comment here :)

Answer (score 1):

First off you have this configuration:

```
accept: '#yes-drop',
```

Usually id's are used only once on the page, you have multiple elements with the same id. I recommend accepting the `.draggable` class.

Now for the problem, you specify `restriction: "parent"` in the configuration. If you remove that the other elements can be dropped like you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a reason for the ID but i dont remenber which one :D
Im gonna test the restriction, I will go back here if that didnt work...